# Android Web View has trouble loading page when buttons are linked to a specific url

Tags: android, webview, navigation

I have an app with a native header and a Webview below it. In this header I have a few links to different pages on the same site. For some reason when I click these links it takes almost twice as long as a link inside of the Webview takes to navigate to the same page.

The code that I am using to navigate to the specific page is below

```
btnCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                mWebView.loadUrl("http://mywebsiteurl.com/categories");
            }
        }
```

If I create the link to this page in HTML and put in on one of the pages it goes much faster. Is there a better way to set up this native button to navigate to the page in my Webview?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
btnCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClint());
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://mywebsiteurl.com/categories");
    });
}

public class MyWebViewClint extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that actually speeds it up a lot.